# Redirect to front page after emptying the shopping cart (ubercart)

Tags: views, 7, ubercart

How can I redirect to the front page after emptying the cart. I am making a commerce site using the Ubercart module, but it is not redirecting to the front page after the cart is empty.

Comment: You could try changing the submit property on a form_alter?

Comment: Have you tried with rules?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [drupal_goto function](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7).

`drupal_goto('<front>');`